# Get official Windows XP virtual machine for Hyper-V

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-xp, virtual-machine, hyper-v

There are many unofficial Windows XP ISO file in numerous of websites. So to create a Windows XP virtual machine, one has to download that ISO and make that virtual hard disk manually. Is there a way to get a pre-build official Windows XP virtual machine from official Microsoft website?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

1. Download a [Windows XP Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC#Windows_XP_Mode) executable file [from Microsoft's Windows XP Mode site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8002).
2. Open the folder containing the executable file (e.g. WindowsXPMode_en-us.exe). **Don't install it.** Unzip that exe file with **7ZIP** by dragging and dropping it into the 7ZIP window. Open **Sources folder** in 7ZIP window, extract **xpm** file.

[image: 2_Windows XP Mode executable]

3. Use 7ZIP to open the **xpm** file that you extracted in the previous step.  Scroll down; select and extract the file named **VirtualXPVHD**.

[image: 3_xpm file]

4. Add the **.VHD** extension to that file name (e.g. VirtualXP.VHD) by using F2 key.

[image: 4_VHD rename]

5. Open Hyper-V, make a new VM, add that previous VHD file (see [procedure](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg318058(v=ws.10).aspx)). Then run that VM.

[image: 5_Running VM]

It is advisable to use it *after making a checkpoint* in Hyper-V.

**Links::**

- Windows XP in VirtualBox:: [Download Windows XP for Free and Legally, Straight From Microsoft](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/download-windows-xp-for-free-and-legally-straight-from-microsoft-si/)
- Windows XP Mode_en-us:: https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/2/C/72C7BAB7-2F32-4530-878A-292C20E1845A/WindowsXPMode_en-us.exe
- Windows XP Mode_N_en-us:: https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/2/C/72C7BAB7-2F32-4530-878A-292C20E1845A/WindowsXPMode_N_en-us.exe

Comment: VirtualBox supports VHD so simply create a Windows XP 32-bit machine and plug-in the VHD in it at the step where you select the disk.

Comment: I have no problem taking snapshots regardless the medium.

Comment: On VirtualBox "PCnet FAST III" network adapter has to be used. As browser for Windows XP, I suggest Firefox 52 ESR (supported until august 2018), because Internet Explorer 6 does not support TLS.

Comment: Links to XP image are no longer valid

Comment: Windows XP mode is still available for download from [the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/windows-xp-mode_20200907). @Biswapriyo, could you please edit your answer to add this link?