# Create Windows XP VM on Windows 10

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, windows-xp, windows-10

I need to create a Windows XP VM so that I can run some legacy software. I have the latest version of Windows 10 on my laptop.

What I've Tried:

1. downloaded an iso image for Win XP from MSDN
2. started hyper-v manager
3. selected "Quick Create"
4. chose local installation source
5. selected my local iso for win XP

A new VM is created ok but when I start it I get the following:

[image: prob1]

I've also followed this post using XPMode but got the same result: https://superuser.com/questions/1230652/get-official-windows-xp-virtual-machine-for-hyper-v

Does anyone know a way around this - or a better alternative?

Comment: Windows XP isn't a supported guest OS in Hyper-V under Windows 10.

Comment: You are not going to be able to run any OS which doesn't support UEFI within a Hyper-V virtual machine.  I suggest you remove Hyper-V and use different hypervisor of your choice to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the advice. Do you know if Vista would work with hyper-v? Or perhaps the Oracle Virtual Box would work with XP?

Comment: Windows XP isn't a supported guest OS as Gen1 or Gen 2 in Hyper-V under Windows 10. - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/plan/should-i-create-a-generation-1-or-2-virtual-machine-in-hyper-v#BKMK_Windows

Comment: @joeqwerty Microsoft doesn't "support" Windows XP anymore. That doesn't mean it won't still work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run Windows XP only as a Generation 1 virtual machine. It cannot be run as a Generation 2 virtual machine, as these only support UEFI boot, and Windows XP only boots in the old school legacy method.

The Hyper-V Quick Create wizard *only* creates Generation 2 virtual machines. To create a Generation 1 virtual machine, select **New** > **Virtual Machine...** and select **Generation 1**.

[image: Hyper-V New Virtual Machine Wizard]

After you finish creating the virtual machine, it will boot Windows XP.

[image: Windows XP - Virtual Machine Connection]

[image: Windows XP - Virtual Machine Connection]

[image: Windows XP - Virtual Machine Connection]

Comment: P.S. I love virtualization so much that [I did this all in a nested VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KASqt.jpg) on my Linux (Fedora) laptop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a Gen 1 VM.  You will also need XP SP3, that's the minimum that's compatible with Hyper-V.  Gen 2 VMs require Win8 and higher,

Comment: Windows XP isn't a supported guest OS as Gen1 or Gen 2 in Hyper-V under Windows 10. - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/plan/should-i-create-a-generation-1-or-2-virtual-machine-in-hyper-v#BKMK_Windows